# how can i use laravel website in CWP (Centos-Web-Panel). without public folder in url?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, nginx, centos-web-panel

*hi, I want to change the root directory of my website which the server panel is CWP `centos-web-panel`. i find a solution that says change `DocumentRoot`and `directory` in `httpd.conf` but I can't change that because a lot of my website using this server. I want to change the root folder in one of my websites.
also, I find another solution which said edit the file.*

`# nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/your_site.conf`

*and add this code to the file*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/your_site/public
ServerName your_domain

<Directory /var/www/html/your_site/>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*but not working.
how I can do that?
are any solution for that or with `.htaccess` or own `laravel` template?*

*so i want to change `/public_html/` to `/public_html/public/` in `centos-web-panel`*
*i using Nginx*

Comment: Rename your server.php to index.php and copy your .htaccess file from public folder and paste it parallel to index.php (which is previously server.php)

Comment: @AnkurTiwari if I only change `server.php` to `index.php`. anyone can download my `.env` file with type `www.example.com/.env` how can I prevent from that?

Comment: You can hide yours.env as well, Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I prefer this answer. which is more secure. and no need to redirect.
create a folder in the public_html maybe `foldername` then move all of files and folders from the `public_html` to the `foldername` after that move all files and folders from `public` laravel folder to `public_html` open `index.php` and edit that like this.*

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/foldername/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/foldername/bootstrap/app.php';
```

*then hide `.env` file with `.htaccess`*

***Finish***

Answer (score 3):

Go to :

```
WebServer Settings -> Conf Editor -> Apache -> /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhosts/
```

Search for **mydomain.ssl.conf** & **mydomain.conf** and click **edit**

[image]

Search for DocumentRoot and change it

From:

```
DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html
```

To:

```
DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/public
```

[image]

**Don't forget to restart Apache after that.**

Done

Comment: This works fine; the only drawback is that you may have to be admin also. If only the user can also do this somehow, then it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in .htaccess

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

and copy index.php file to root folder and follow steps
https://hellocoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel/
https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following thing to point your application without public in the `URL`:

Rename your server.php to `index.php` and copy your `.htaccess` file from public folder and paste it parallel to `index.php` (which is previously `server.php`)

And to hide your `.env` a file you need do add following lines in your `.htaccess` file

```
# Disable index view
Options -Indexes

# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: how I can do that for all file and folder?

Answer (score 0):

if you have access ssh
remove public_html folder

```
rm -rf public_html/
```

create short cut to public folder (laravel) , we will put laravel in same level public_html

```
ln -s laravel/public public_html
```

now its done