# .htaccess for a Laravel app installed in a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I've a domain, like `www.example.com`

The main site is on FTP space visible as `/example.com`

I installed (copy/pasted, sigh... :(  ) my Laravel app under `/example.com/laravel_app`.

I am able to open the laravel app, and it's fully working, if I access using full url `http://www.example.com/laravel_app/public/index.php`.

The problem is that, obviously, I'd like to access it using only the path `http://www.example.com/laravel_app`.

In the root of `laravel_app`, I tried to paste this `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

While in the `/example.com/laravel_app/public` i'm using this `.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel_app/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So my question is NOT related the `.htaccess` of app's public folder, but the `.htaccess` for app's root folder.

How can I succesfully serve

`http://www.example.com/laravel_app/public/index.php`

accessing

`http://www.example.com/laravel_app`

?

Actually I got Laravel returning a 404

I tried this variant (seen I some question very similar to this one)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

But with this I got apache returning a forbidden

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037835/how-can-i-use-laravel-website-in-cwp-centos-web-panel-without-public-folder-i/55038127#55038127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have installed your application on shared hosting and ssince it's running Apache this solution should work.

Revert your .htaccess back to its original/what was deployed with laravel.

Ideally you shouldn't have your project uploaded in public_html as it exposes all the files to the web.

Move all your project files **except** `public` to a directory below `public_html`.

Eg.

```
/home/<username>
  [laravel] <-- Make this directory
  [public_ftp]
  [public_html]
  [ssl]
  etc..
```

Then in your `public_html` move the files inside your `public` folder to the directory you want to serve your files (address you want to go to to use your app).

```
/home/<username>/public_html/laravel-app
  [public_html]
    [laravel-app]
     -index.html
     -robots.php
     -.htaccess
     -[css]
     -[js]
     -[svg]
     etc..
```

Now edit your `index.html` file in the `laravel-app` folder and change both:

`require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

..to reflect the path where you moved yoru project folder.

`require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';`
`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';`

Essentially in this context `../` means back one folder, so the aim is to take it back to where it will find the `laravel/vendor/` folder, vice-versa.

Realistically that should sort your issue out and make for a more secure application as your .env and composer, etc. files will not be publically available without messing with your .htaccess.

Oh, also here is the default `.htaccess` code which should be under your public folder `<project>/public`:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```