# Laravel app in subfolder under public html

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

Good day,

i have a laravel project running under domain.co.zw and domain root folder is pointing to public_html. I then created a subdomain but it is pointing to a subfolder called mainsystem which is under then public_html.

Now i have condifguired the htaccess for the website in public_html, hoow best can i configure for the laravel app in subfolder mainsystem with domain database.domain.co.zw

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mainsystem/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So you just want to have one Laravel app configured in the subfolder? Or do you want to keep the existing app where it is and put a new project in the subfolder? Regardless I think you can find an [answer here where this has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098754/htaccess-for-a-laravel-app-installed-in-a-subfolder).